# Swiperefreshlayout not refreshing for layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

swiperefreshlayout not working with diffrent view. I have created main layout and included a layout in it as shown in code.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_post_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <include layout="@layout/layout_util" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwipeRefreshLayout only supports a single `ListView` or `GridView` child. [Official src](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html#AddSwipeWidget)

So you can try [SwipeRefreshMultipleViews](https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/index.html)

Edited:

First create on Custom Class for MultiSwipeRefreshLayout

```
public class MultiSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private View[] mSwipeableChildren;

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Set the children which can trigger a refresh by swiping down when they are visible. These
     * views need to be a descendant of this view.
     */
    public void setSwipeableChildren(final int... ids) {
        assert ids != null;

        // Iterate through the ids and find the Views
        mSwipeableChildren = new View[ids.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            mSwipeableChildren[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
        }
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(can_child_scroll_up)

    /**
     * This method controls when the swipe-to-refresh gesture is triggered. By returning false here
     * we are signifying that the view is in a state where a refresh gesture can start.
     * <p>
     * <p>As {@link SwipeRefreshLayout} only supports one direct child by
     * default, we need to manually iterate through our swipeable children to see if any are in a
     * state to trigger the gesture. If so we return false to start the gesture.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mSwipeableChildren != null && mSwipeableChildren.length > 0) {
            // Iterate through the scrollable children and check if any of them can not scroll up
            for (View view : mSwipeableChildren) {
                if (view != null && view.isShown() && !canViewScrollUp(view)) {
                    // If the view is shown, and can not scroll upwards, return false and start the
                    // gesture.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(can_child_scroll_up)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(can_view_scroll_up)

    /**
     * Utility method to check whether a {@link View} can scroll up from it's current position.
     * Handles platform version differences, providing backwards compatible functionality where
     * needed.
     */
    private static boolean canViewScrollUp(View view) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            // For ICS and above we can call canScrollVertically() to determine this
            return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(view, -1);
        } else {
            if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
                // Pre-ICS we need to manually check the first visible item and the child view's top
                // value
                final AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) view;
                return listView.getChildCount() > 0 &&
                        (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0
                                || listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < listView.getPaddingTop());
            } else {
                // For all other view types we just check the getScrollY() value
                return view.getScrollY() > 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(can_view_scroll_up)
}
```

then change your layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<in.muthu.stackoverflow.ui.widget.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/contact_screen_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/empty_text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</in.muthu.stackoverflow.ui.widget.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

> Note: change in.muthu.stackoverflow.ui.widget with your
>   MultiSwipeRefreshLayout with your package

And in your java code you should do this,

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (MultiSwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSwipeableChildren(R.id.contact_screen_list);
```

Comment: Edited my answer have a look.